# Strange whois results

Tags: whois

Did a whois today on Facebook (because it was unreachable) and noticed strange things coming up. Any idea what this is all about?

(Ignore the brush marks, hiding the stuff that was behind)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yep, spammers are even targeting WHOIS records.

- http://fnord.phfactor.net/2009/05/13/whois-spam/
- http://hughw.blogspot.com/2007/09/whois-spam.html

Your whois for `domain.com` is being treated as actually being a search for `*domain.com*`. Entirely harmless, if a little scary the first time you run across it.

Answer (score 1):

The [beyondWhois](http://beyondwhois.com) search seems to pull that up, but a regular [Whois.net](http://whois.net) search pulls up the correct information.

Comment: I am just doing this from command line on my computer. Does that mean that there is something going on with my isp or dns?

Comment: No, it's nothing wrong with you, your ISP, your DNS, or anything else. It's harmless.

Answer (score 0):

To get more details, see [How to use command line whois for “spam infected” domains like apple.com?](https://superuser.com/questions/37954/how-to-use-command-line-whois-for-spam-infected-domains-like-apple-com)