# Whois Domain Info

Tags: whois

I did an IP lookup this morning to trace its origins based on an email I received.  Within a section labeled 'Whois Domain Info', it reads the following:

> Whois Server Version 2.0
>
> Domain names in the .com and .net domains can
>   now be registered with many different
>   competing registrars. Go to
>   http://www.internic.net for detailed
>   information.
>
> COMCAST.NET.EXAMPLE.COM
>
> COMCAST.NET
>
> ...

Now I realize this is one of Comcast's IPs and I have replaced the actual text with 'EXAMPLE.COM'.  My question is related to what 'COMCAST.NET.EXAMPLE.COM' is supposed to represent.  How does the IP I looked up relate to example.com in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Though not your question, Suma is right about SpamCop. That makes me wonder *what* you actually did. You got some IP, then got the name `comcast.net` out of that (maybe just a `ping`?), and then did a `whois comcast.net`? That explains you're seeing the thing that I believe is Whois Spam. No need to protect southridgelacrosse.com -- they are abusing the internet alright. Or did you do something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange whois results](http://superuser.com/questions/30388/strange-whois-results)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's just [Whois Spam](http://www.erik-rasmussen.com/blog/2006/12/05/whois-spam/) by `example.com`.

See [How to use command line whois for “spam infected” domains like apple.com?](https://superuser.com/questions/37954/how-to-use-command-line-whois-for-spam-infected-domains-like-apple-com) here at Super User.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of tracking source of email I would highly recommend http://www.spamcop.net/ - it can parse mail headers in a lot more reliable way than most of us can.

As for addresses like COMCAST.NET.EXAMPLE.COM, this is actually NOT a comcast IP. It is just an IP which attempts to look like a comcast one. If tracking the real owner, you always need to process the address from the end.